# Why is there a VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_INDEX_INPUT_BIT and do I have to use it?

Tags: vulkan

According to the docs at Khronos.org the PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_INPUT_BIT is:

```
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_INPUT_BIT specifies the stage of the pipeline where vertex and index buffers are consumed
```

So that flag covers both vertex input and index input. However I've seen a:

```
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_INDEX_INPUT_BIT
```

in my Vulkan header. Have they now been separated into two separate flags? And do I have to use them to flush of invalidate caches with respect to indices?

Answer (score 3):

`VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_INPUT_BIT` is part of [`VkPipelineStageFlagBits`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPipelineStageFlagBits.html).  It covers both vertex and index buffers.

`VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_INDEX_INPUT_BIT` is part of [`VkPipelineStageFlagBits2`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPipelineStageFlagBits2KHR.html).  It covers only index buffers.

> Have they now been separated into two separate flags?

[image]

There *are* two flags in the new structure, one for index and one for vertex.  They are, respectively

- `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE_INPUT_BIT` for vertex buffers only
- `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_INDEX_INPUT_BIT` for index buffers only

However, there is also a `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_VERTEX_INPUT_BIT` definition which is their bitwise or, so it acts just like `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_INPUT_BIT` in the older versions of the barrier functions.

> do I have to use them to flush of invalidate caches with respect to indices?

It depends on what function you're calling.  If you're calling `vkCmdPipelineBarrier`, you don't need to think about any of this, because it still uses `VkPipelineStageFlagBits`.

If you're calling `vkCmdPipelineBarrier2` then you need to use the newer `VkPipelineStageFlagBits2`.  But if you don't care about the distinction between the index and vertex buffers in the pipeline, then you could just swap out `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_INPUT_BIT` with `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_VERTEX_INPUT_BIT` directly and everything should work the same as before, because `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_VERTEX_INPUT_BIT` intentionally covers both vertex and index buffers.

Comment: So in other words only use vkCmdPipelineBarrier2 if you need the extra granularity of distinguishing vertex and index inputs, right?